# ¿Como leo un arreglo desde JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un arreglo generado desde una tabla MySql por medio de PHP, deseo utilizar el script que brinda Google para mostrar en un mapa un marcador desde la latitud y longitud almacenada en el arreglo. ¿Como seria el procedimiento, cuando yo tengo los datos de lat y long en $arreglo['latitud'] y $arreglo['longitud']???

```
<script>
    var map;
    var latitud = -38.858228;
    var longitud = -60.057083;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: latitud, lng: longitud},
         zoom: 18
        });
      }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxDngjvn6vXgmzU4oA5lSqDeyaC-OJ6sQ&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Comment: Muestra el código que usas y una imagen con la estructura de tu array

Comment: @CamiloVasquez Una imagen no. Mejor es pegar el código de la estructura.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: El título de la pregunta no tiene mucha relación con el contenido. Preguntas cómo leer un arreglo pero en la pregunta dices cómo puedes marcar la distancia de las coordenadas en Google Maps. Necesitas poner el código que llevas hasta el momento para mostrar el mapa y lo que te han comentado previamente.

Comment: No Guz... el marcador es el globito que señala un punto en Google maps "Marker" y por otro lado no quiero marcar distancias... no puse nada de ello.

Comment: @RicardoPastuszek Vale, el marcador. Te recomiendo poner un título **expresivo**, el que tienes es realmente demasiado genérico. Así mismo, la próxima vez coloca el código desde el inicio para que tengas asistencia precisa. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que veas cómo funciona el sitio y así ganas tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el código que muestras en ningún momento estas creando un marcador, simplemente estas centrando el mapa en la ubicación que quieres mostrar, para agregar un marcador tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    var map;
    var latitud = $arreglo['latitud'];
    var longitud = $arreglo['longitud '];
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: latitud, lng: longitud},
         zoom: 18
        });
      }

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat:parseFloat(latitud), lng: parseFloat(longitud )},
          map: map,
          title: 'Titulo del marcador'
       });
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDxDngjvn6vXgmzU4oA5lSqDeyaC-OJ6sQ&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Answer (score -3):

Es muy general lo que preguntas, porque dependiendo de muchas variables los procedimientos serían distintos. En el caso de que el arreglo que obtienes de PHP esté siendo directamente desplegado en tu HTML, podrías ponerlo en algun elemento HTML oculto, como por ejemplo un:

```html
<input id="miArregloP" hidden value="<?php echo json_encode(miArrgloDeMySQL); ?>"/>
```

Luego esa información en formato JSON la podrás extraer con javascript de la siguiente forma:

```js
var miArregloP = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('miArregloP').value);
```

Y teniendo el arreglo en javascript podrás usarlo con tu API de google, sin problemas.

En el caso de que quieras consumir un servicio a través de JavaScript, eso ya es una historia más larga y te recomiendo que lo estudies.

Comment: Hola @LeonardoDíaz , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y de igual forma leer bien la pregunta del OP para poder responder de buena forma, lo que  hacemos en la comunidad es aclarar las preguntas que tienen y no confundirlos mas.